# How to convert Timestamp from CET mariadb to java UTC Localdatetime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mariadb, timezone

I have a CET MariaDB Database containing a lot of Timestamp (Unix Epoch) and i want to convert this data to LocalDateTime with UTC Timezone.

As you can see my MariaDB Database used the CET timezone (the first line is the command, the second is the sql result) :

```
select @@system_time_zone as tz;
CET
```

And my application used UTC (the first line is the command, the second is the console result) :

```
System.out.println("Setting the timezone::>" + TimeZone.getDefault());
Setting the timezone::>sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

I use springboot 2.6.4.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.FieldNameConstants;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "example")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldNameConstants
public class ExampleEntity implements IEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long notificationId;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}
```

This entity is used by Spring jpa repository (findAll method) :

```
import com.application.infra.db.entity.ExampleEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<ExampleEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ExampleEntity> {

}
```

And i have configured springboot datasource :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.name@'
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://mariadbdatabase:6666/example}
    username: example_user
    password: example_password
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

Is it possible to get a LocalDateTime converted to UTC TimeZone ?

> I have try to use `timezone` connector parameter but it does nothing. :(

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please add more details on how you are reading from database? JDBC? JPA? other? Share the relevant code.

Comment: I have add some information. I use spring jpa with springboot datasource configuration over jdbc connecror and jpa crud repository to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time zone configured in the database differs from the default time zone of the application we need to instruct JDBC to use the database time zone for the conversion. Add following property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=CET
```

Comment: Oh no ! I have made a mistake. :( I thought the timezone was the one we wanted after conversion. So, it's work fine ! Is it possible to do the same thing with jdbc connection url ? I have read there is a https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/ with `timezone` parameter but it didn't work for me.

Comment: The driver parameter works but the other way round. It means you would set it to auto or to UTC. Recommended: `jdbc:mariadb:localhost/?timezone=auto` Check here for details: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#timezone-consideration

Comment: Yes, i have already read the documentation about Mariadb connector. I don't know why, but it doesn't work on my application. Thank you so much for your response !

Comment: Maybe old version? timezone parameter since 3.0.0

Comment: Yes. Springboot 2.6.4 include org.mariadb.jdbc.mariadb-java-client:2.7.5. So, i have open the Options.java file and there is an option  serverTimezone but this change nothing for me...